# Linux Serial Console Size

Tags: linux, terminal

I am using Yacto based linux distribution on embedded control board. When I access the terminal serially(via rs232 port), the default size is 80 chars.
I have changed this by running following commands

```
>stty size
0 0 
>shopt -s checkwinsize
>stty rows 60 cols 160
>shopt -u checkwinsize
>stty size
60 160
```

Terminal has new setting, however following a reboot, they are back to default! I tried "stty --save" after making changes, but of no use. The user is root, as its dev board.

I believe it is possible to preserve the settings between sessions/after reboots.

Can anyone point me where are the stty settings gets saved on rootfs? I can so edit that file with new row/column info without any other changes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may look into `setserial` and its `/etc/serial.conf`, though an initscript would work just as well. What is your init system?

Comment: "/etc/serial.conf" file does not exists!
>> though an initscript would work just as well.
Do you mean adding my commands/ 'setserial' to init.d scripts?

Comment: I notice 'etc/terminfo' directory which seems to have some binaries, but not use what they are used for ? Could these be any useful for what I wanted to do?

Comment: `setserial` isn't necessarily installed by default. Adding a script in `init.d` is sufficient if that's how your system controls the startup. I don't know what you might find in `/etc/terminfo`

Comment: I finally achieved this by adding the instructions to /etc/rc.local file, so it gets executed on every boot. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I finally achieved this get the settings on every boot by adding the instructions to /etc/rc.local file, so it gets executed on every time.
I hoped that there was a better solution with terminal configuration files on Linux rather than adding commands to rc.local. But it does the job on my development board :-)